# Division of modified bessel of the second kind over the first kind

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

$A(\lambda \rho )$=$1-\frac{1}{2\lambda \rho}-\frac{1}{8(\lambda)^2(\rho)^2}$

I need reference for this equation, can any one help me ?
I used this equation in my work in statistic , another information about this function

$A(\lambda \rho)$=$\frac{I_1(\lambda\rho)}{I_0(\lambda \rho)}$ =$1-\frac{1}{2\lambda \rho}-\frac{1}{8(\lambda)^2(\rho)^2}$
where $I_0$ is the modified bessel function of the first kind and $I_1$ is the second 
Where i can find the proof of the previous function .

Comment: What reference are you expecting to exist? This seems like a pretty ordinary function.

Comment: @mixed I edit my post to more information

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{I_1(\lambda\rho)}{I_0(\lambda \rho)}$ =$1-\frac{1}{2\lambda \rho}-\frac{1}{8(\lambda)^2(\rho)^2}\quad$ is false.

For example $\quad\frac{I_1(0)}{I_0(0)} =0\quad$ while $\left(1-\frac{1}{2(0)}-\frac{1}{8(0)^2}\right)$ is infinite.

You can check it for other values of $\lambda\rho$. In all cases $\quad\frac{I_1(\lambda\rho)}{I_0(\lambda \rho)}\neq 1-\frac{1}{2\lambda \rho}-\frac{1}{8(\lambda)^2(\rho)^2}$.

This seems an asymptotic approximate :
$$\frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)}\simeq 1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^2}+...\qquad x\text{ large.}$$

This is consistent with the approximate for large argument (from "An Atlas of Functions", §50:9:3, p.495, J.Spanier, K.B.Oldham, Springer-Verlag, 1987 ).

$$I_\nu(x)\simeq \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\left(1-\frac{1}{x} \right)^\mu \qquad; \qquad \mu=\frac{\nu^2}{2}-\frac18$$

It can be derived that :
$$\frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)}\simeq \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}+...\qquad x\text{ large.}$$

Comment: please put the web site, i cant find 50:9:3 in pg 495  2

Comment: That is not a site. That is a book, probably expansive to buy. On can find more general formulas of asymptotic series for $I_\nu(x)$ on Wolfram-MathWorld, but it would be arduous to simplify them : http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/06/02/

Comment: ftp://nozdr.ru/biblio/kolxo3/M/MRef/Oldham%20K.,%20Myland%20J.,%20Spanier%20J.%20An%20atlas%20of%20functions%20(2ed.,%20Springer,%202010)(ISBN%200387488065)(O)(762s)_MRef_.pdf  I cant find the exactly function i written in the book !!!!!!!

Comment: Well, I knew that a there is a new edition of "An Atlas of Functions", but I didn't know that it is now on free access on the web. Apparently, a lot has changed compare to the old edition. The numbering of the sections and equations are not the same. Nevertheless, if you consider the Eqs.$(49:6:2)$ and $(49:6:3)$ in the new edition, you can derive $\frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)}\simeq 1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^2}+...\qquad x\to\infty$.

Comment: Anyways, now you have the answer to your initial question : $1-\frac{1}{2\lambda \rho}-\frac{1}{8(\lambda)^2(\rho)^2}$ is the first terms of the asymptotic series of $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\lambda \rho}}$, isn't it ? . Of course, that is not equal to $\frac{I_1(\lambda\rho)}{I_0(\lambda \rho)}$. Only the first terms of the asymptotic series coincide. This is not an equality, but an approximate.